# androidx biometric library uses missing resource

Tags: android, android-databinding, androidx

Was trying to include `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha03` as one of my android project dependencies, but gradle sync throws this error:

> Error: Resource type cannot be an empty string (at
>   'strokeColor' with value '?android:/attr/colorAccent').

The file raising the red flag is:

> app/build/intermediates/data-binding-layout-out/debug/drawable-v23/fingerprint_dialog_error_to_fp.xml,

Some other info that could be relevant:

- compileSDK: 28
- minSDK: 21
- targetSDK: 28

Please note that I have not done any other migration to androidx, and I am still using an old gradle plugin and gradle itself.

Any help is really appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It seems like `android:/attr/colorAccent` should have been `android:attr/colorAccent` instead? Is that it?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/004ede837759913ad056a7df08c1eb3a9f47ba6d%5E1..004ede837759913ad056a7df08c1eb3a9f47ba6d/

Comment: You can't use `androidx.biometric` unless you've switched to everything AndroidX - you can't mix `androidx` with pre-AndroidX libraries